# Loop of checkboxes to add objects to model list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model (called plan) which one of its properties is a list (`ICollection`) of  Exercises (which is another model):

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
```

So i tried to create a view that creates a plan and another view to add Exercises to the plan from exercises in the database.
So i did a loop that ranges all the exercises from the DB and for each one i added a check box with and id same as the id of the exercise and i thought i could do something with it but i tried so many things and ways and i couldn't even sent the input of the check boxes to the controller.
I must say that i'm kinda new with programming with mvc and i tried to look all over the internet and i didn't really know people who knows to program so this is really my last chance to solve it. Sorry if it was a long post or too easy for you to even comment but i really need this.

This is very specific for my project and what i stacked on was to sent the input to the controller but i'm open to different solutions cause i'm desperate.

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> AddExercises(string id,int[] selectedExercises)
{
    List<Exercise> list = new List<Exercise>();
    foreach (int i in selectedExercises)
    {
        list.Add(db.Exercises.Find(i));
    }
    db.Plans.Find(id).Exercises = list;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

I am sure its wrong and the view i tried is:

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "Plans"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    foreach (var i in Model.Exercises)
    {
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Level)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Description)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.MoreDescription)</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = i.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = i.Id }) |
                    <input type="checkbox" class="selectedObjects" id="i.id" /> |
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
    @Html.ActionLink("Finish", "AddExercises")
}
```

I use viewModel PlanExercise in this view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checkboxes do not have either a `name` attribute or a `value` attribute so there is nothing to submit. You html needs to be

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedExercises" value="@i.id" />
```

and then in order to submit the form, you need a submit button (remove `@Html.ActionLink("Finish", "AddExercises")`)

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

and the form needs to be (assuming the controller is `FinishController`)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddExercises", "Finish"))
```

and the method needs to be marked with the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Comment: Well i tried but it seems that when i add the httppost attribute the method doesnt even called so i thought it something about what the method gets (between the brackets in the head of the method)

Comment: OK, Just noticed you form is also wrong - its needs to be `@using (Html.BeginForm("AddExercises", "Finish"))` (assuming your controller is named `FinishConroller`)

Comment: Yes you were right but now it tells me that there's problem in this line:  foreach (int guid in selectedExercises)

Comment: What problem (I cant guess!). And why are you calling a value which is type of `int` guid? Are the values really typeof `int` or are they typeof `Guid`?

Comment: Well i don't know what the value type should be, this is why im here... but no, the word guid is only because i copied it. and this is the eror headline: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. what that means

Comment: It means that something is `null` Inspect the value of `selectedExercises`. Is it `null`? and what is the actual html generated for one of your checkboxes? Is it `value="1"` (i.e. a value that can be converted to `int`)

Comment: i'm not sure i understand your question, why would it be null? i checked the checkboxes and clicked save. I said it in the last comment, i don't know what the type is, i was guessing that its int and the id is int as well so there shouldn't be a problem. The real question is what is sent to the controller? is it the id? and if it is, what is the type of the id?

Comment: FGS! What is the actual html that is generated in your html for one of the checkboxes.

Comment: Listen, i'm sorry that i miss understood you, my English anyway isn't really good. i'll be glad if you could explain what you meant by what generate for one of the checkboxes.

Comment: Run you app. Inspect the view source and look at the html you have generated. You will see a series of `<input type="checkbox" name="selectedExercises" value="someValueHere" />` - what is it.

Comment: value:"i.id"
valueAsDate:null
valueAsNumber:NaN  i guess this is the null you were talking about, why did it happened?

Comment: almost done, now it tells me this:                                                                 The argument types 'Edm.Int32' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 68.                                    For the line:                                                                                                          db.Plans.Find(id).Exercises = list;

Comment: What is it that you trying to do with that line of code?. I need some sleep so suggest you ask a new question. I cant design you whole app in comments.